# How to solve for an unkown probability distribution within a hierarchical model?

Tags: probability, random-variable, hierarchical-bayesian, importance-sampling, approximate-bayesian-computation

### The Problem

Given probability distributions $P(\theta)$ and $P(X)$, and given an inverse function $Y=f^{-1}(X,\theta)$ that returns a unique $Y$. How can one estimate the unkown distribution $P(Y)$ in the following hierarchical model?

$\theta = f(X,Y)$

$Y \sim P(\cdot)$

$X \sim P(\cdot)$

### The Questions

- What is this problem called, is it a defined problem within statistics with a name?
- What methods exist (or could be reasonably proposed) to solve for $P(Y)$?

### Current Thoughts

At first it seems like a solution is to simply sample independently from $P(\theta)$ and $P(X)$ to estimate $P(Y)$ using the function $Y=f^{-1}(X,\theta)$, but that would be incorrect: the hierarchical model above implies a dependence between $X$ and $\theta$ such that one would need to instead sample from the joint distribution $P(\theta,X)$ (which is not given).

It seems like this problem may be related to importance sampling or approximate Bayes computation.

Comment: This is a generalized [deconvolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconvolution) problem. (if $f(X,Y)=X+Y$ then it is exactly deconvolution)

Comment: I do not think the concept of "estimation" applies in that case since this is not a statistical problem. Mathematically, assuming $\theta$ and $X$ are independent, the [change of variable formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables) provides the distribution of $Y$ since $f$ is invertible wrt its first entry. Simulation-wise, generating $(\theta,X)$ produces exact generations of $Y$. If the joint distribution of $(\theta,X)$ is unknown, there is no answer to the question.